# EasyMonkeyDevice not found error while running monkeyrunner python script

Tags: android, python, jython, monkeyrunner

I want  to run monkeyrunner python script.

```
from com.android.monkeyrunner import MonkeyRunner, MonkeyDevice
from com.android.monkeyrunner.easy import EasyMonkeyDevice
from com.android.monkeyrunner.easy import By
from modjy.modjy_params import INTEGER


# Connects to the current device, returning a MonkeyDevice object
device = MonkeyRunner.waitForConnection()

easyDevice = EasyMonkeyDevice(device)
MonkeyRunner.sleep(2)
easyDevice.touch(By.id('id/btnSignUp'),MonkeyDevice.DOWN_AND_UP)
```

Below is the command I am using to run script

```
c:\path_to_and_sdk_tool> monkeyrunner test.py
```

But I am getting error when I get "EasyMonkeyDevice" Object.

```
File "C:\python\test.py", line 19, in <module>
            easyDevice = EasyMonkeyDevice(device)
        java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not connect to the view server
                at com.android.chimpchat.hierarchyviewer.HierarchyViewer.setupViewServer
        (HierarchyViewer.java:57)
                at com.android.chimpchat.hierarchyviewer.HierarchyViewer.<init>(Hierarch
        yViewer.java:43)
                at com.android.chimpchat.adb.AdbChimpDevice.getHierarchyViewer(AdbChimpD
        evice.java:95)
                at com.android.monkeyrunner.easy.EasyMonkeyDevice.<init>(EasyMonkeyDevic
        e.java:64)
                at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)

                at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)

                at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Sou
        rce)
                at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
                at org.python.core.PyReflectedConstructor.make(PyReflectedConstructor.ja
        va:67)
                at org.python.core.PyJavaType$1.new_impl(PyJavaType.java:517)
                at org.python.core.PyType.invokeNew(PyType.java:466)
                at org.python.core.PyType.type___call__(PyType.java:1558)
```

Please share some links from where i can get EasyMonkeyDevice import

Answer (score 1):

You have to implement ViewServer to use EasyMonkeyDevice : 
https://github.com/romainguy/ViewServer
because easyMonkey uses Hierarchy Viewer.

In your activities :

Enable ViewServer for hierarchy viewer like this :

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         ViewServer.get(this).addWindow(this);
     }

     public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        ViewServer.get(this).removeWindow(this);
     }

     public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        ViewServer.get(this).setFocusedWindow(this);
     }
}
```

Comment: I added this code line in activity onCreate(). But still it is giving same error.

Comment: Updated answer. You need to set focusedwindow in onResume().  Sorry I forgot this.

Comment: I have added the code mentioned by you. Still not working for me. What did I miss?

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can use **A[ndroidViewClient](https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient)** and you won't be forced to implement a `ViewServer` in your application.

This will do the same as your previous script:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

from com.dtmilano.android.viewclient import ViewClient
ViewClient(*ViewClient.connectToDeviceOrExit()).findViewByIdOrRaise('id/btnSignUp').touch()
```

You can also generate this kind of script or unit tests just by running `culebra -UG` (in AndroidViewClient tools) and click on the UI representation of the device to automatically generate the `touch()` invocations.

Comment: How can I Install AndroidViewClient?